# Login message is truncated on Ask Question page

Tags: bug, design, mobile-web

**You must be logged in to ask a question** message goes out of the mobile screen when user goes to the Ask Question page. Issue exists on both Stack Overflow and Programmers.SE

**Screenshot from Nexus 4:**

[image]

Culprit seems to be the `val-message` css class having a fixed width of 400px.

```
.val-message {
  margin: 5px 5px 10px 5px;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was fixed by Someone.

[image]

There is no more fixed width in CSS:

```
.val-message {
    margin: 10px 0;
    padding: 10px
}
```